# How to know whether I installed Apache Airflow successfully?

Tags: airflow

My OS is Mac OS. I followed airflow official installation guide to install. But when I test: `airflow test tutorial print_date 2015-06-01` from [airflow testing](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html#testing) it doesn't print any output. The result is here.[image: Result Image]. I wonder did I install it successfully? I've run other commands on the official airflow testing page. They report no error.

Comment: Update: e.g. It should print something like Output: Thu Oct 18 00:16:04 PDT 2018(current time) while nothing shows.

Comment: Oh no an image of text that isn't searchable nor scrollable!

Answer (score 0):

So far I see only WARNING output, it doesn't mean that airflow isn't running nor installed improperly. You'd have an easier time testing your install with `airflow list_dags` and you probably must run `airflow initdb` before most of the commands (and look at the `airflow.cfg` file).